# Configure the Smidge library for asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, smidge

Scott Hanselman today [blogged](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/LightweightBundlingMinifyingAndCompressionForCSSAndJavaScriptWithASPNETCoreAndSmidge.aspx) about [Smidge](https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge). I think the library is pretty nice and I'm evaluating the library.

I like the option to define logic for Debug and Production like in the sample:

```
bundles.CreateJs("test-bundle-3", "~/Js/Bundle3")
   .WithEnvironmentOptions(BundleEnvironmentOptions.Create()
      .ForDebug(builder => builder
         .EnableCompositeProcessing()
         .EnableFileWatcher()
         .SetCacheBusterType<AppDomainLifetimeCacheBuster>()
         .CacheControlOptions(enableEtag: false, cacheControlMaxAge: 0))
      .Build()
```

However I couldn't find out what defines `Debug`/`Production`. Is there a way to tell the system when he's in debug and when he is in production mode?

Also seems that the Version can only be defined in the config.

```
"smidge": {
  "dataFolder" : "App_Data/Smidge",
  "version" : "1"
}
```

Is there an option do define the version in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the system when he's in debug and when he is in production mode?

This is covered in the docs here: https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge/wiki/Rendering#debugging and it's based on the `debug="true"` attribute of the html tag.

> Also seems that the Version can only be defined in the config.

The Version is controlled in Smidge by the `Smidge.Cache.ICacheBuster`. There are currently 2 implementations of this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Based on a static string specified in config
/// </summary>
public class ConfigCacheBuster : ICacheBuster

/// <summary>
/// Creates a cache bust value for the lifetime of the app domain
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Essentially means that all caches will be busted when the app restarts
/// </remarks>
public class AppDomainLifetimeCacheBuster : ICacheBuster
```

So it's possible to specify one of these or implement your own. If you implement your own, you need to add it to your container like:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheBuster, MyCacheBuster>();
```

Then you can specify options for your bundle (there are various ways to do this), for example:

```
bundles.CreateJs("test-bundle-2", "~/Js/Bundle2")
    .WithEnvironmentOptions(BundleEnvironmentOptions.Create()
            .ForDebug(builder => builder
                .EnableCompositeProcessing()
                .SetCacheBusterType<MyCacheBuster>())
            .Build()
    );
```

You can also see this startup class for examples: https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge/blob/master/src/Smidge.Web/Startup.cs#L126

Comment: Thank you so much. I went for the solution of serpent5 for defining the version but will definitely switch to my own Implementation of ICacheBuster.

Comment: Just implemented my own CacheBuster. Works perfectly. You can also define your buster as as default instead of defining it for every bundle. `bundle.DefaultBundleOptions.ProductionOptions.SetCacheBusterType<CacheBuster>();`

Comment: @Shazwazza i am trying to set up smidge for my project and use Smidge.InMemory package. However, when i add AddSmidgeInMemory() i don't see that my bundles update on file change or when i edit "version" in my appSetting.json. 
What am i missing? I want my bundles in memory to be updated whenever i edit any of input css/js files. When using physical files , bundles update normally.

Answer (score 2):

There's a section in the [Rendering docs](https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge/wiki/Rendering) on debugging, included here for completeness:

> By default Smidge will combine/compress/minify but while you are developing you probably don't want this to happen. Each of the above rendering methods has an optional boolean 'debug' parameter. If you set this to true then the combine/compress/minify is disabled.

It goes on to include an example of how to manage this using ASP.NET Core MVC's environment Tag Helper:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="my-awesome-js-bundle" type="text/javascript" debug="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="my-awesome-js-bundle" type="text/javascript"></script>
</environment>
```

`SmidgeConfig` obtains the version from `IConfiguration` directly, as can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge/blob/master/src/Smidge/SmidgeConfig.cs#L34):

```
public string Version => _config["version"] ?? "1";
```

This means you can't change it within the code itself, but you might be able to add something to the ASP.NET Core configuration system in order to provide a different value for this.

EDIT: I looked into the configuration thing a bit more and concluded that you could achieve what you want with [`AddInMemoryCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.memoryconfigurationbuilderextensions.addinmemorycollection?view=aspnetcore-2.0). The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#in-memory-provider-and-binding-to-a-poco-class) give a good example of how to use this, so I've included a context-specific example for you below, adapted from the example code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"smidge:version", "1"}
};

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

// ...
// Whatever code you're using to set up the builder.
// If you're in ASP.NET Core 2, this will be setup differently, but the docs cover it well.
// ...

builder.AddInMemoryCollection(dict);
```